# Webpack - How to require an entry bundle inside another javascript file

Tags: webpack, bundle, require

I have 2 entry points: One for the main app, and one for legacy part of the app.

The legacy.js, is being bundled just as I want it to, like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['file1', 'file2'],
        legacy: ['legacyfile1', 'legacyfile2'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'js/[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
        chunks: ['app'] // Only include app bundle - Legacy will be required in the legacy javascript file.js at runtime.
    }),
}
```

This generates the two bundles, and only the app.js bundle is injected into index.html.

Then inside legacy.js, I want to require the legacy bundle at the top of the file, something like this (all does not work, Webpack can not find the modules):

```
require('./dist/js/legacy.js');
require('./js/legacy.js');
require('dist/js/legacy.js');
require('/js/legacy.js');
```

**How is it possible with Webpack to require a Webpack bundled file into a javascript file at runtime?**

Thanks for those who find the time to consider this!

Answer (score 0):

Webpack bundles each entry point into a normal script file which does not export anything. So you can't `require` or `import` it.

One solution (other than sharing code via global scope) is to find the common sharable code of both bundles, and extract it into a separate module so you can import it from either codebase.

Comment: Hi Son, Thanls for the answer. Would it be possible by using the bundle-loader somehow, any experience on that?

Comment: I'm afraid no because bundle-loader still requires the file to export something.